# is it possible to save data from a html form to an excel file with web services?

Tags: html, web-services, web, newsletter

I have made a newsletter with html and CSS, and in that newsletter I have 4 text boxes which takes the users name,family name,phone number,email address.Can I use a web service to transfer this data from the HTML form to an excel file, or a database on a host?

Is it possible at all? saving data from a html form to an excel file with web services?

If yes, how?

Comment: why down vote?please give me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume you save this data into a database. That would be my approach at least.

So:

- Send the data using a form to your server application (ASP.NET or something alike);
- Save it in the database (or process it right away);
- Then use a package like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate the Excel file in a web service. See their project page about the how to do that;
- Return the result to the client.

Comment: what do you mean by "Send the data using a form to your server application (ASP.NET or something alike)"?

Comment: You need a server to send the data to. Client side solutions for this are not recommended in my opinion. Read into some technology like ASP.NET or PHP.

Comment: is there any client side solution at all?

Comment: There is, but they only work on IE and with right permissions set. I would not recommend it (and hesitate to post any sample).

Answer (score 0):

yes thats possible but you would need a fifth button like send information that would post those fields to a php script on your server and then save it into your database

look here to see how to post information to your server
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

and here for a small mysql tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp